# React hooks: Not getting the state update when using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having an issue when mixing `useState` and the `useEffect` hook. I can't seem to reference the new `query` state in `onReady()`.

```
function Foo() {
  const [ query, setQuery ] = React.useState('initial query');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    myLibClient.onReady(onReady)
  }, []);

  function onReady() {
    const newQuery = myLibClient.createQuery({ options });
    setQuery(newQuery);
    console.log(query); // initial query :(
  }

  return null;
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that like `this.setState` in the class-based react components, the `setQuery` function also sets the state asynchronously.

See [Reference react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and [RFC: Why it is asynchronous?](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710)

So if you try to access the value just after setting the state, you'll get the older value.

You can verify this behavior here. https://codesandbox.io/s/2w4mp4x3ry. (See the file named Counter.js) 
You'll see that before and after values for counter are same.

If you want to access the updated value, you can access it in the next render cycle. I have created another example where you can see that new query value is being rendered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8l7mqkx8wl (See the file named Counter.js)

Comment: I had the same problem and using the same approach that you described here, it worked fine. Do you think this is fine? Or too much of a workaround?

Comment: IMO, This is fine and preferred way.